# Would user frustrations come under the umbrella of a user journey?

Tags: user-journey, user-story

I am designing a time planning tool. I have created several personas, which are using multiple other tools to achieve something that should be easily achievable  with the software I am designing.

I have written user journeys of the users using those other tools. I want to use those descriptions to create new user-stories for my project.

Is there a name for these problem descriptions that aren't part of the actual project, but instead focus on the problems that users have with using other software?

Answer (score 2):

You could mention users current difficulties here in your user journey as this would form part of a reason as to why they would use your system but should not really be your sole focus for the entire user journey, you should include other information. Check out the link below it just covers what user journeys should contain.

[User Journeys - What they should contain](http://theuxreview.co.uk/user-journeys-beginners-guide/)

There is not another name for this. There is a nice article here which describes different types of user journeys:

[Breakdown of user journeys](https://deniziren.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/epic-breakdown-structure-types-of-user-stories/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are analysing other products, this is called **competitor analysis**.

If you have found problems with the user experience while evaluating these products, it is simply **usability problems** in competitor products.

In a document, there will be a section called *competitor analysis*, under which there'll be a section called 'usability issues' (possibly under a section called 'evaluation').

Answer (score 2):

The User Journey is used to map the current journey a typical user might take to reach their goal while **highlighting gaps, pain points or frustrations** but also **opportunities of a better experience**, both from the perspective of the user and the business. This is where typically **competitor analysis** are conducted to redesign a journey free from frustration and aimed at outpacing the competition.

User frustrations are born out of **usability issues, lack of coherent information architecture as well as from poor interaction design.**

Competitor Analysis should in principal tackle all these aspects, the outcome of which should be a reviewed user journey that ensure that frustrations or pain points are addressed and resolved while adding new features or improving existing ones .

Hope that helps